# Route post method giving error - Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting a strange error while using Route::Post(). When I try to access the URL (http://localhost/project/public/testnew) I get an error instead of getting "Hello" on screen.

Here is my code from routes.php-

```
Route::post('/testnew', function(){
  return "hello";
});
```

And this the error I am getting -

[image]

Somebody help

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash.

```
Route::post('testnew', function(){
  return "hello";
});
```